# How to specify that T is inherited from other interface. Universal comparator

Tags: c#, .net

I have a function that verifies if a number falls between two other numbers a and b. For doubles this function looks like this:

```
public static bool IsBetween(this double num, double minValue, double maxValue)
{
   return (num >= minValue && num <= maxValue) 
          || (num >= maxValue && num <= minValue);
}
```

The problem here, however is that I need to be able to check if integer or decimal falls within this range. So I would have to specify an overload with signature:

```
public static bool IsBetween(this int num, double minValue, double maxValue)
```

Question: is there a way to make this universal by adding  where T is inherited from IComparable. Here is what I am looking for:

```
public static bool IsBetween <T : IComparable> (this T num, K minValue, K maxValue)
{
   return (num >= (T)minValue && num <= (T)maxValue) 
       || (num >= (T)maxValue && num <= (T)minValue);
}
```

I could probably try to cast everything in `double` but I it would be an overkill if all values are integers or decimals.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You write this as:

```
public static bool IsBetween <T, K>(this T num, K minValue, K maxValue)
    where T : IComparable
    where K : IComparable
{
    // ...
```

That being said, you might want to write this using [IConvertible](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iconvertible.aspx) instead of `IComparible`, given that you're casting.  This would let you do cleaner conversions to a common type.

Comment: The compiler doesn't like this:num >= (T)minValue && num <= (T)maxValue

Comment: namely: operator '>=' cannot be applied to instances of type T

Comment: @AstroSharp Which is why I had suggested using `IConvertible` - this would let you convert both to a similar type.  There is no "magic bullet" here, though - Generics (unlike C++ templates) don't really support this well.  It would require something like `IArithmetic` (which has been a long, long time request on Connect for .NET)

Comment: @AstroSharp Right now, the best option is typically to use `IConvertible`, convert both types to double or Int64 (depending on one of the types), and compare that way.  It's ugly, but it's really about the only way to get there.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a `where` class to the right of the signature, something like this:

```
public static bool IsBetween<T, K>(this T num, K minValue, K maxValue)
        where T : IComparable<T>
        where K : IComparable<T>
{
    // ...
}
```